# Regularity of weak solution for $u_t - \Delta u = f$ with $u(0) = u_0 \in L^1(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, bochner-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain, and consider the equation
$$u_t - \Delta u = f$$
$$u(0) = u_0 \in L^1(\Omega)$$
with Neumann BCs (or Dirichlet if convenient) where $f$ is smooth.

Using energy/variational methods, is it true that there is a solution $u$ in some Bochner space? What spaces does the solution lie in? What can I expect? I would like something like $u \in L^2(0,T;H^1)$ with $u' \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$ which is standard for $u_0 \in L^2$ but not sure about the $L^1$ case. In particular, I would like some regularity on the gradient and the time derivative (so I do not want "very weak solutions").

I am well-versed in the theory for $u_0 \in L^2$ and am not interested in that case. Please note that I want to do this in a variational setting so semigroup/classical methods are out of the questions. Thanks for any help.